# if Hessian matrix of a function has positive real eigenvalues, then function is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra

Can we say that if Hessian matrix of a function has positive real eigenvalues, then function is positive definite? Is it true? Would you recommend a document for me to read on this subject?

$V=\alpha x^2+\alpha y^2+ z^2$, I know this function is positive definite for $\alpha >0$. But I wonder if it would be correct to check with its Hessian matrix as I asked above?

Comment: Will you please explain what has your question to do with [tag:lyapunov-functions]?

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be positive definite? Are you asking about quadratic forms?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry I was going to use this information for lyapunov stability analysis. I removed the tag.

Comment: @ttt "positive-definiteness" is a concept that typically applies only to matrices or quadratic forms (since every quadratic form is canonically identified with a symmetric matrix). The result is __obviously false as you stated it__ by simply considering a positive definite quadratic form plus a negative function at zero whose second derivative is null (a constant function will do). Like $x^2+y^2+z^2-1.$

Comment: @WillM. This is the definition I'm interested in my problem: Let $(x^∗,y^∗)$ be fixed point. $V(x,y)>0$ for all $(x,y)≠(x^∗,y^∗)$ and $V(x^∗,y^∗)=0$. Then$ V(x,y)$ is positive definite function. #lyapunov-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simple counterexamples, such as $V(x,y)=x+x^2+y^2$, which is obviously not positive definite although its Hessian has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=2$.

Comment: $V$ is not a quadratic form.

Comment: @WillM.: There is no mention of quadratic forms in the question, it just says “function”. And judging from the tag lyapunov-functions (although it's now removed), this seems to be in a context where not only quadratic forms can be said to be positive definite, but any function $f$ such that $f(\mathbf{0})=0$ and $f(\mathbf{x})>0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Let $H$ be the Hessian matrix of a twice differentiable function. Then $H$ is symmetric. Then, $H$ can be orthogonally diagonalisable $H = \Gamma D \Gamma^\intercal,$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries the eigenvalues of $H$ and $\Gamma$ is the orthogonal matrix whose columns are unitary eigenvectors of the $H.$ If $D$ is positive (meaning all eigenvalues are positive), you can trivially define $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and then you decompose the Hessian as $\Gamma D^{\frac{1}{2}} D^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma^\intercal.$ Let $x \neq 0.$ If you pre and post multiply by $x^\intercal$ and $x$ you find that $x^\intercal H x = \left\| D^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma^\intercal x \right\|^2 > 0$ sincc $D^{\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma^\intercal$ is invertible.

Comment: I can see a downvote but no comment. What is wrong with my answer in your view?